# How can I use win32gui in order to have an app run in the background?

Tags: pywin32

I was able to find a great piece of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9494913/revisions) on how to create a Tray app using the win32gui module.

However, that app runs based on a function called `notify` which only runs when the mouse is moving over the icon.

How can I make the app do something constantly in a loop, regardless of what the user does?

(In other words, I want to use win32gui in a non-event-based way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `win32gui.PumpMessages` (which runs its own loop) in the code, replace it with the following loop:

```
while True:
    your_function()
    win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

This will allow you to run your own functions in the program loop.